# Error while checking the clickable web element

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am facing problem while checking the clickable web element.
So i have to check the alphabetic series and some of the alphabet are clickable and some are not clickable.

i used for loop for it starting with `xpath` of alphabet 'A'
and going in loop till alphabet 'Z'.

but as soon as `xpath` of alphabet A is click & pass it goes to alphabet 'B'
which is not clickable and due to this whole script is getting fail.

**here is the code**

```
for(int j=3; j<=26;j++) {
    String T1 =".//*[@id='twctvEl']/div/div/div[1]/ul/li[";
    String T2 = "]/a";
    String T12 = T1+j+T2;
    chrome.findElement(By.xpath(T12)).click();
    String alpha =chrome.findElement(By.xpath(T12)).getText();
    System.out.println("checking the alphabet"+alpha);
}
```

Please advice here

**NOTE:** In the series of alpha bet from A-Z only B,Q,S,X,Y,Z are not clickable rest all are clickable.

Comment: What is the exception occurred when its getting failed??

Answer (score 2):

You can add waits before element to become clickable:

```
for(int j=3; j<=26;j++) 

{

    String T1 =".//*[@id='twctvEl']/div/div/div[1]/ul/li[";
    String T2 = "]/a";        
    String T12 = T1+j+T2;        
    WebElement el = chrome.findElement(By.xpath(T12));        
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout);            
    WebElement el= wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element));
    el.click();        
    String alpha =el.getText();       
    System.out.println("checking the alphabet"+alpha);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the element is visible and enabled before clicking on it

```
WebElement letter = chrome.findElement(By.xpath(T12));
if (letter.isDisplayed() && letter.isEnabled()) {
    letter.click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems that when you click the element "A", it take you to another page or context and for this reason, during next iteration chrome driver is not able to find your Element "B" using xPath.